# What do clang and gcc qualify as variable being unused

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

I noticed in a PR review an unused variable and we were wondering why compiler didn't catch that. So I tested with godbolt the following code with bunch of unused variables and was surprised that some were reported as unused but others not. Even though all of them are unused.

```
#include <string>

struct Index
{
  Index(int index) : m_index(index) {}
  int m_index;
};

int main()
{
    std::string str = "hello"; // case 1. no warning here - unexpected
    int someValue = 2; // case 2. warning - as expected
    const int someConstant = 2; // case 3. warning - as expected
    Index index1(2);  // case 4. just as equally not used but no warning - unexpected
    // here using the assignment but do get a warning here
    // but the str assignment doesn't give a warning - weird
    Index index2 = 2; // case 5.
    Index index3{2}; // case 6. just as equally not used but no warning - unexpected
    Index index4 = {2}; // case 7. just as equally not used but no warning - unexpected
    return 0;
}
```

> warning: unused variable 'someValue' [-Wunused-variable]

> warning: unused variable 'index2' [-Wunused-variable] (warning only on clang, not on gcc)

> warning: unused variable 'someConstant' [-Wunused-variable]

So what do clang and gcc qualify as unused? What if I'm using a lock? I declare it but don't use it directly but use it for automatic releasing of a resource. How do I tell the compiler that I am using it if one day it starts to give a warning about the lock?

```
int g_i = 0;
std::mutex g_i_mutex;  // protects g_i
 
void safe_increment()
{
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_i_mutex);
    ++g_i;
    // g_i_mutex is automatically released when lock goes out of scope
}
```

flags: -Wunused-variable
clang: 14.0.0
gcc: 11.3

Comment: The [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute is what you should use to tell the compiler that a variable (or function) might be unused, and that it's okay.

Comment: Note: GCC seems to have separate flag for `Index x = ...;`, `-Wunused-but-set-variable`: https://godbolt.org/z/f4s13s55a

Comment: As for the problem of detecting that variables might be unused, the heuristics are rather complex. It's easy to either make it too strong (in which case your example with the lock would be marked as an unused variable, which is wrong) or to relaxed (in which case some more unexpected cases of not emitting warnings might crop up).

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that the line is drawn at POD types, just looking at your examples. Adding the language-lawyer tag might get you an answer from the standard.

Comment: It seems you managed to answer a good part of your question yourself. It sounds like you express an expectation that any object declared but never read from should be warned about. But in the second part of your question you share an example of why that isn't possible, or at least would lead to false positives.

Comment: By the way there's a simple explanation why the string and the `Index` objects counts as used: Their destructor will be called when the objects life-time ends. The destructor call is effectively *using* the object.

Comment: It is a bit weird that clang would warn on `index2` but not the other unused `Index` variables. GCC making a division based on POD-ness of the type seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason why there's no warning is that variables of non-trivial class type aren't technically unused when you initialize them but then never access them in your function.

Consider this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/qx44dTq37):

```
struct Trivial {};

struct NonTrivial {
    NonTrivial() {
        //Whatever
    }
};

void test() {
    Trivial t;
    NonTrivial nt;
}
```

GCC warns about `Trivial t;` being unused since this declaration never causes any user-defined code to run; the only thing that's run are the trivial constructor and trivial destructor, which are no-ops. So no operation at all is performed on `Trivial t` and it is truly unused (its memory is never even touched).

`NonTrivial nt;` doesn't cause a warning, however, since it is in fact *used* to run its constructor, which is user-defined code.

That's also why compilers are not going to warn about "unused lock guards" or similar RAII classes - they're used to run user-defined code at construction and destruction, which means that *they are used* (a pointer to the object is passed to the user-defined constructor/destructor = address taken = used).

This can further be proved by [marking the object's constructor with the `gnu::pure` attribute](https://godbolt.org/z/E5r6sY3cr):

```
struct Trivial {};

struct NonTrivial {
    [[gnu::pure]] NonTrivial() {
        //Whatever
    }
};

void test() {
    Trivial t;
    NonTrivial nt;
}
```

In this case, GCC warns about both of them because it knows that `NonTrivial::NonTrivial()` doesn't have side-effects, which in turn enables the compiler to prove that construction and destruction of a `NonTrivial` is a no-op, giving us back our "unused variable" warning. (It also warns about `gnu::pure` being used on a void function, which is fair enough. You shouldn't usually do that.)

Clang's warning about the following code also does make sense.

```
struct Hmm {
  int m_i;
  Hmm(int i): m_i(i) {}
};

void test() {
  Hmm hmm = 2; //Case 5 from the question
}
```

This is [equivalent](https://cppinsights.io/s/9c70e44c) to the following:

```
void test() {
  Hmm hmm = Hmm(2);
}
```

Construction of the temporary `Hmm(2)` has side-effects (it calls the user-defined constructor), so this temporary is not unused. However, the temporary then gets moved into the local variable `Hmm hmm`. Both the move constructor and the destructor of that local variable are trivial (and therefore don't invoke user code), so the variable is indeed unused since the compiler can prove that the behavior of the program would be the same whether or not that variable is present (trivial ctor + trivial dtor + no other access to the variable = unused variable, as explained above). It wouldn't be unused if `Hmm` had a non-trivial move constructor or a non-trivial destructor.

Note that a trivial move constructor leaves the moved-from object intact, so it truly does not have any side-effects (other than initializing the object that's being constructed).

This can easily be verified by deleting the move constructor, which [causes both Clang and GCC to complain](https://godbolt.org/z/nbMcKf5ec).

Comment: Ok so we get no warnings on unused non-trivial type objects because they run user defined code in the ctor and those can have all sorts of side effects that may be needed. Makes sense. But then there is that one case on clang Index index2 = 2; // case 5. Why is that a warning all of a sudden? Why we get a warning there but not with the Index objects? After reading your answer I would not expect a warning on any of the Index objects.

Comment: ```Index i = 2;``` is equivalent to ```Index i = Index(2);```, which means that a temporary gets constructed and moved from. The move constructor and destructor of your class are both trivial, meaning that the construction of the stack variable itself doesn't have any side-effects, only the construction (and immediate destruction) of the temporary has some (it invokes user-defined code). So the stack variable is unused. But it's still counter-intuitive.

Comment: I still have some doubts. I thought that types whose ctor takes only one argument then the objects can be created in two ways: `Index i(2);` or `Index i = 2;` the latter being syntactic sugar for the first one and effectively does the same as the first one and not doing a temporary and move it.

Comment: Cppinsights says otherwise: https://cppinsights.io/s/9c70e44c There is, in fact, a temporary that's moved.

Comment: If that really does a temp and a move then it's all clear. I have to verify that non-explicit single param ctor and the assignment construction thingy. I tried it with this https://godbolt.org/z/KxnWKzeKq and got 
ctor(int)
ctor(int)
printed out, not seeing any moves.

Comment: Hmm, that's really weird. Maybe Clang optimizes this even with -O0? Cppinsights still shows the calls to the move constructor there. (Move constructors may get optimized away even if they have side-effects, i.e. if they print something.) Or maybe there is no move after all and Clang is just emitting an extraneous warning? That'd mean Cppinsights is wrong. I'm not sure.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer. There is in fact a move from a temporary. Deleting the move constructor makes Clang unhappy: https://godbolt.org/z/nbMcKf5ec - So Clang really does create a temporary, move from it, and then optimize away the move even with -O0. GCC does the same thing.

Comment: Nice finding with deleting that move ctor not compiling with clang and gcc. More weirdness comes from the fact that **msvc accepts** your example when deleting the move ctor. I'll need to ask a c++ language lawyer in a different question who is conforming to the standard and who is not. I think msvc is correct here. Why make a temp and a move when just creating the object directly is enough.

Comment: well on gcc depends. Starting from version 11.x compiles and on 10 and below not